# Unable to connect to MongoDB client and insert data when using promises

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am experimenting nodeJS and I'm getting an error while trying to establish a connection to the MongDB Client. I have used promises for better readability and now I'm unable to connect. The code consist of connecting to the database, inserting a document, retrieving the entries and then clean the database by dropping the collection I had added, but the connection fails. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```js
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const assert = require("assert");
const dboper = require("./operations");

const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const dbname = "conFusion";

MongoClient.connect(url).then((err, client) => {
    assert.strictEqual(err, null);
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    const db = client.db(dbname);
    dboper
      .insertDocument(db, {
        name: "Vadonut",
        description: "Test"
      }, "dishes")
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("Insert Document:\n", result.ops);

        return dboper
          .findDocuments(db, "dishes")

          .then((docs) => {
            console.log("Found documents:\n", docs);

            return dboper.updateDocument(
              db, {
                name: "Vadonut"
              }, {
                description: "Updated Test"
              },
              "dishes"
            );
          })
          .then((result) => {
            console.log("Updated document:\n", result.result);

            return dboper.findDocuments(db, "dishes");
          })
          .then((docs) => {
            return db.dropCollection("dishes");
          })
          .then((result) => {
            console.log("Dropped collection: ", result);

            client.close();
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

this is the error I'm getting once I try connecting to the server

```js
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected values to be strictly equal:
+ actual - expected ... Lines skipped

+ MongoClient {
+   [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
+   _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
+   _eventsCount: 0,
+   _maxListeners: undefined,
+   s: {
+     dbCache: {},
+     options: {
+       connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
+       dbName: 'admin',
+       db_options: {
+         readPreference: 'primary',
+         read_preference_tags: null
+       },
+       mongos_options: {
+         socketOptions: {}
+       },
+       promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
+       readPreference: ReadPreference {
+         mode: 'primary',
+         options: undefined,
+         tags: undefined
+       },
+       read_preference_tags: null,
+       rs_options: {
+         socketOptions: {}
+       },
+       server_options: {
+         socketOptions: {}
+       },
+       servers: [
+         {
+           host: 'localhost',
+           port: 27017
+         }
+       ],
+       socketOptions: {},
+       socketTimeoutMS: 360000
+     },
+     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
+     sessions: [],
+     url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/'
+   },
+   topology: <ref *1> Server {
+     [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
+     _events: [Object: null prototype] {
+       all: [Function: bound onceWrapper] {
+         listener: [Function (anonymous)]
+       },
+       authenticated: [Function (anonymous)],
...
- null
...
    at /Users/thierrymwamba/Desktop/code/NodeJS/node-mongo/index.js:9:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  generatedMessage: true,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: [MongoClient],
  expected: null,
  operator: 'strictEqual'
}
```

the expected output is as follow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUaxN.png)

Comment: See this [Connection Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/) using NodeJS driver. You will also find the CRUD operations example within the same documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and I was able to fix it by just swapping (err, client) together in the first .then method

Wrong Code:
MongoClient.connect(url).then((err, client)

Correct Code:
MongoClient.connect(url).then((client, err)